# Does SQL server log when and who enabled / disabled jobs by default?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs, logging

Is there any default logging or history of when a SQL job was enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer would be no. I don't think there is any system table that captures or logs this change. However you can find the details from last modified date of sql job for any change.

Please refer to some great insights as answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19101654/3898986) by Aaron and Crafty DBA. This should help for future reference.